# Libgdx texture region to texture

Tags: java, textures, libgdx

I want to use `setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);` on my image, taken from textureAtlas. when I use

```
TextureRegion texReg = textureAtl.findRegion("myImage");
Sprite = new Sprite(texReg);
```

it's works fine, but if i try

```
TextureRegion texReg = textureAtl.findRegion("myImage");
Texture myTexture = new Texture(texReg.getTexture());
myTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
Sprite mySprite = new Sprite(myTexture);
```

mySprite contains all textureAtlas images. How to set to Texture single image from textureAtlas?

Comment: Maybe try to use the `.setFilter` on all the image and then load the specific one.

Answer (score 4):

Your last line should be:

```
Sprite mySprite = new Sprite(texReg);
```

Texture can represent a single image or multiple images (texture atlas). When there are multiple images, each is location in its texture region. You can only apply filtering to the entire texture and therefore all the images in it. If you want to apply it only to a single image, it needs to be in a separate texture.

So here is what you were doing with your code:

```
// get the image for your game (or whatever) object
TextureRegion texReg = textureAtl.findRegion("myImage");
// get the texture that is the 'container' of the image you want
Texture myTexture = new Texture(texReg.getTexture());
// apply filtering to the entire texture and all the images
myTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
// set the entire texture as the image for your sprite (instead of only a single region)
Sprite mySprite = new Sprite(myTexture);
```

Comment: @AntonSobolev You mean this does not work for you? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

### Use Pixmap

---

```
fun TextureRegion.toTexture(): Texture {
    val pixmap = Pixmap(regionWidth, regionHeight, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)

    if (texture.textureData.isPrepared.not()) texture.textureData.prepare()
    val texturePixmap = texture.textureData.consumePixmap()

    pixmap.drawPixmap(texturePixmap, 0, 0, regionX, regionY, regionWidth, regionHeight)

    val newTexture = Texture(pixmap)

    texturePixmap.dispose()
    pixmap.dispose()

    return newTexture
}
```

---

> Don't forget to **dispose** the **texture | pixmap!**

---

Be careful with **pixmap.dispose()**. If you use a texture bitmap after this conversion and convert that texture again, you may encounter memory errors. The solution is to simply pass the flag to use **pixmap.dispose()** or not.

Comment: If you copied parts of this answer from ChatGPT, you must disclose which part was copied. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing